# Incorrect output post JSON.parse(...)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

The controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "channelIntentionDetails.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody
  Report getChannelIntentionDetails(@RequestBody SearchParameters searchParameters) {
    LOGGER.info("In ReportController.getChannelIntentionDetails(...), searchParameters " + searchParameters);

    return channelDetailsService.getIntentionDetails(searchParameters);
  }
```

The Report POJO :

```
public class Report {

  private Map<String, Collection<String>> parameterWiseResult;
  private Collection<String>              results;
  private String                          result;
  private String                          spid;
.
.
.
}
```

The **results** collection holds JSON strings returned from a MongoDB collection

The JS AJAX snippet :

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","channelIntentionDetails.html",false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    xmlhttp.send(stringifiedSearchParameter);

    alert("Plain AJAX response "+ xmlhttp.response);
    alert("After JSON.parse(...) "+ (JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response)).results);

drawIntentionPieChart((JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response)).results);

function drawIntentionPieChart(data) {

        //alert("In drawIntentionPieChart(...) " + intentionGooglePieChart);

        if (intentionGooglePieChart == null
                || intentionGooglePieChart == 'undefined') {
            //alert("Creating new intentionPiechart");
            intentionGooglePieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
                    document.getElementById('intentionPiechart'));
        }

        intentionGooglePieChart.clearChart();

        //var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        var jsonData = data;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Intention');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Share');

        for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

            /* alert("Intention : " + jsonData[i]._id.Intention_category
                    + " Count : " + jsonData[i].count); */

            data.addRows([ [ jsonData[i]._id.Intention_category,
                    parseInt(jsonData[i].count) ] ]);

        }

        var options = {
            title : 'Intention Analysis',
            titleTextStyle : {
                color : '#0E5EAE'
            },
            fontSize : 14,
            width : 390,
            height : 200

        };

        intentionGooglePieChart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

**First alert** where "results" is an array

```
Plain AJAX response {"parameterWiseResult":null,"results":["{ \"_id\" : { \"SpId\" : 352 , \"Intention_category\" : \"Opine\" , \"Report_Id\" : 2 , \"Channel_Id\" : 1} , \"count\" : 1}","{ \"_id\" : { \"SpId\" : 352 , \"Intention_category\" : \"Wish,Purchase\" , \"Report_Id\" : 2 , \"Channel_Id\" : 1} , \"count\" : 1}","{ \"_id\" : { \"SpId\" : 352 , \"Intention_category\" : \"Complain\" , \"Report_Id\" : 2 , \"Channel_Id\" : 1} , \"count\" : 1}","{ \"_id\" : { \"SpId\" : 352 , \"Intention_category\" : \"Purchase\" , \"Report_Id\" : 2 , \"Channel_Id\" : 1} , \"count\" : 2}","{ \"_id\" : { \"SpId\" : 352 , \"Intention_category\" : \"None\" , \"Report_Id\" : 2 , \"Channel_Id\" : 1} , \"count\" : 93}"],"result":null,"spid":null,"idvallistsearchprofile":null,"idvallisttags":null,"spmaster":null,"competitiveParameters":null}
```

Second alert where after JSON.parse(...), the array braces viz. [] are gone :

```
After JSON.parse(...) { "_id" : { "SpId" : 352 , "Intention_category" : "Opine" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 1} , "count" : 1},{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 352 , "Intention_category" : "Wish,Purchase" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 1} , "count" : 1},{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 352 , "Intention_category" : "Complain" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 1} , "count" : 1},{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 352 , "Intention_category" : "Purchase" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 1} , "count" : 2},{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 352 , "Intention_category" : "None" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 1} , "count" : 93}
```

Later,I get errors when I try to iterate this parsed result.

**TypeError: jsonData[i]._id is undefined**

```
data.addRows([ [ jsonData[i]._id.Intention_category,
parseInt(jsonData[i].count) ] ]);
```

Where am I messing up?

Comment: The parsed result returns array of objects... How are you iterating the parsed result?? Can you share the code snippet..

Comment: Added the snippet where the error surfaces.

Comment: The contents of array are represented as strings with double quotes for each object. You need to change the web service to return the contents as objects instead of strings.

Comment: Check the answer below.. you should follow one of the options

Comment: I need to know the root cause - why the array representation is lost after JSON.parse(...)? Is it because each 'String' in Collection<String>results is a string representation of JSON?

Comment: Yes while serializing the json in your web service, you are using Collection of Strings instead of collection of objects. That is the reason for error.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to fix your problem.

Option 1: Change the data format returned from your service

Your POGO should look like below, if you want to return collection/array of objects from your web service.

```
public class Report {

    private Map<String, Collection<String>> parameterWiseResult;
    private Collection<MyObject>            results;
    private String                          result;
    private String                          spid;

    //Setters and Getters
}

public class MyObject {

    private Id _id;
    private int count;

    //Setters and Getters

    private class Id {
         int SpId;
         String Intention_category;
         int Report_Id;
         int Channel_Id;

         //Setters and Getters 
    }
}
```

Option 2: Double parse the string to convert inner String to Object in Javascript. Within for loop, you need to parse each element of array to JSON like below:

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(jsonData[i]);
data.addRows([ [ myJson._id.Intention_category, parseInt(myJson.count) ] ]);
```

Comment: Option 1 : Infeasible as there are large no. of disparate reports and a different MyObject cannot be created

Option 2: In place already but it's an awful workaround :(

Comment: Option 1: If there are large no. of disparate reports and cannot define different objects, then take generic collection (eg. HashMap) to store key, value pairs instead of string. Option 2: I too understand that it is an awful workaround..

Comment: If you use some proper json library (eg. Google's Gson library) for serializing your json at controller, it will convert hashmap to jsonObject